# Как убрать полосу горизонтальной прокрутки, появляющейся в результате картинок слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите решить проблему, пожалуйста. Есть пять картинок в слайдере, окно слайдера вмещает три картинки, соответственно две остаются скрытыми, но все равно увеличивают ширину страницы. Появляется полоса горизонтальной прокрутки, если ее прокрутить до конца, то видно просто большее белое поле. Слайдер расположен по середине страницы. Подскажите, можно это как-то убрать?

```
<div class="slider">
      <div class="slide slide-1"><img src="..\slider-1.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="slide slide-2"><img src="..\slider-2.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="slide slide-3"><img src="..\slider-3.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="slide slide-4"><img src="..\slider-4.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="slide slide-4"><img src="..\slider-5.png" alt=""></div>
      <button class="slider__btn slider__btn-right">&rarr;</button>
      <button class="slider__btn slider__btn-left">&larr;</button>
</div>
```

```
const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
const btnRight = document.querySelector(".slider__btn-right");
const btnLeft = document.querySelector(".slider__btn-left");

let currSlide = 0;

function goToSlide (slide) {
  slides.forEach(function (s) {
    s.style.transform = `translateX(${401 * (-slide)}px)`;
  });
}

goToSlide(0)

function nextSlide() {
  if (currSlide === 2) {
    currSlide = 0
  } else {
    currSlide++;
  }
  goToSlide(currSlide)
}

function prevSlide() {
  if (currSlide === 0) {
    currSlide = 2
  } else {
    currSlide--
  }
  goToSlide(currSlide)
}

btnRight.addEventListener("click", nextSlide);

btnLeft.addEventListener('click', prevSlide)
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `css` свойство `overflow-x: hidden;`

```css
.slider{
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, "пустое" пространство все равно осталось.